# Why does the window handle not get stored properly?

Tags: c++, winapi, window, hwnd, createwindow

First you get a MCWE. You know probably better than me how to use it but I would recommend to build a C++ project from scratch and add it then. It uses Unicode character set, make sure to use `windows` as the SubSystem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#using <System.dll>

const int CANVAS_HOR_OFFSET = 10;
const int CANVAS_VER_OFFSET = 10;
const int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
const int CANVAS_HEIGTH = 480;

const int OUTPUT_VER_OFFSET = 10;
const int OUTPUT_HEIGTH = 120;

static class UiObjects
{
public:
    enum ObjectClass { Custom };

    struct Object {
        LPWSTR lpClassName;
        LPWSTR lpWindowName;
        DWORD dwStyle;
        LONG x;
        LONG y;
        LONG nWidth;
        LONG nHeigth;
        HMENU hMenu;
        HWND hObjectWnd;
        ObjectClass objectType;
        COLORREF color;
    };

    Object Canvas, Output;

    std::vector<Object> Objects;

    UiObjects();
} MyObjects;

UiObjects::UiObjects() {
    Canvas = {
        L"myVirtualSandbox Canvas Class",
        L"Canvas",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        CANVAS_HOR_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_VER_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_WIDTH,
        CANVAS_HEIGTH,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        ObjectClass::Custom
    };
    Objects.push_back(Canvas);

    Output = {
        L"EDIT",
        L"Output",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        CANVAS_HOR_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_VER_OFFSET + CANVAS_HEIGTH + OUTPUT_VER_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_WIDTH,
        OUTPUT_HEIGTH,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        ObjectClass::Custom
    };
    Objects.push_back(Output);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
);

LRESULT CALLBACK canvasWndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
);

int __stdcall wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
) {
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"myVirtualSandbox Window Class";

    HWND hApplicationWnd;
    MSG msg = { };
    // A window class defines a set of behaviors that several windows 
    // might have in common. Every window must be associated with a 
    // window class. To register a window class, fill in a "WNDCLASS" 
    // structure and call "RegisterClass" function afterwards.
    WNDCLASS applicationWndClass = { };

    applicationWndClass.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    applicationWndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    applicationWndClass.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&applicationWndClass);

    // Create the window.
    hApplicationWnd = CreateWindow(
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hApplicationWnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hApplicationWnd, nShowCmd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
) {
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HINSTANCE hInstance;
        WNDCLASS canvasWndClass;

        hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        canvasWndClass = { };

        canvasWndClass.lpfnWndProc = canvasWndProc;
        canvasWndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
        canvasWndClass.lpszClassName = L"myVirtualSandbox Canvas Class";

        RegisterClass(&canvasWndClass);

        // The following loop iterates through the container of user 
        // interface objects.
        for (int i = 0; i < MyObjects.Objects.size(); i++) {
            UiObjects::Object& Object = MyObjects.Objects[i];

            HWND hObjectWnd;

            hObjectWnd = CreateWindow(
                Object.lpClassName, // Window class
                Object.lpWindowName,    // Window text
                Object.dwStyle, // Styles 
                Object.x, // Horizontal position 
                Object.y, // Vertical position 
                Object.nWidth, // Width
                Object.nHeigth, // Height
                hWnd, // Parent window
                Object.hMenu, // No menu.
                hInstance,
                NULL // Pointer not needed.
            );

            MyObjects.Objects[i].hObjectWnd = hObjectWnd;
        }

        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    // To paint the window the "WM_PAINT" message has to be 
    // received by the window. It is sent by either the program 
    // itself or the operating system.
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // The "rcPaint" member of the "PAINTSTRCUT" structure 
        // returns a "RECT" structure that specifies the upper 
        // left and lower right corners of the rectangle in which 
        // the painting is requested.
        PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
        HDC hDeviceContext;

        HBRUSH hBrush;

        hDeviceContext = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
        hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(66,66,66));

        // Paint application background.
        FillRect(
            hDeviceContext,
            &paintStruct.rcPaint,
            hBrush
        );

        DeleteObject(hBrush);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);

        break;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK canvasWndProc(
    HWND hCanvasWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
) {
    switch (uMsg)
    {

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        POINT point = { };

        point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Clicked in Canvas.");

        HWND hOutputWnd = MyObjects.Output.hObjectWnd;

        // Check if hObjectWnd is a valid handle
        if (IsWindow(MyObjects.Output.hObjectWnd))
        {
            SendMessage(MyObjects.Output.hObjectWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)L"Test.");
        }
        else {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Is not..");
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hCanvasWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I create windows by iterating through `Objects` in the `WM_CREATE` message of the parent window.

I also register a custom window class to be able to have custom event handling on that object. In case of `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` of this "sub"-procedure I want to modify another child windows text by sending a message to it.

The Output is "Is not.." since the window handle is not passed properly but what am I doing wrong?

I tried to pass the variable as a pointer but that didn´t make a difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `WM_CREATE` loop, you are assigning the new `HWND` to a *copy* of the `Object` from the vector. You are not updating the original `Object` in the vector.

Change this:

```
UiObjects::Object Object = MyObjects.Objects[i];
```

To this:

```
UiObjects::Object& Object = MyObjects.Objects[i];
                 ^
```

Also, note that `Canvas`, `Output`, etc are separate `Object`s than the ones stored in the `Objects` vector. So, `Output.hObjectWnd` etc are likewise not being updated by your `WM_CREATE` loop, either.

---

**UPDATE**: Indeed, you are filling `Canvas`, `Output`, etc with data, and then pushing *copies* of those objects into your `Objects` vector. So, even if your `WM_CREATE` code were assigning the new `HWND`s to the `Objects` elements correctly, `Canvas`, `Output`, etc would still not get the `HWND`s correctly.

To do what you are attempting, you need to change your `Objects` vector to hold `Object*` pointers instead of `Object` instances, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#using <System.dll>

const int CANVAS_HOR_OFFSET = 10;
const int CANVAS_VER_OFFSET = 10;
const int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
const int CANVAS_HEIGTH = 480;

const int OUTPUT_VER_OFFSET = 10;
const int OUTPUT_HEIGTH = 120;

static class UiObjects
{
public:
    enum ObjectClass { Custom };

    struct Object {
        LPWSTR lpClassName;
        LPWSTR lpWindowName;
        DWORD dwStyle;
        LONG x;
        LONG y;
        LONG nWidth;
        LONG nHeigth;
        HMENU hMenu;
        HWND hObjectWnd;
        ObjectClass objectType;
        COLORREF color;
    };

    Object Canvas, Output;

    std::vector<Object*> Objects;

    UiObjects();
} MyObjects;

UiObjects::UiObjects() {
    Canvas = {
        L"myVirtualSandbox Canvas Class",
        L"Canvas",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        CANVAS_HOR_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_VER_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_WIDTH,
        CANVAS_HEIGTH,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        ObjectClass::Custom
    };
    Objects.push_back(&Canvas);

    Output = {
        L"EDIT",
        L"Output",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        CANVAS_HOR_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_VER_OFFSET + CANVAS_HEIGTH + OUTPUT_VER_OFFSET,
        CANVAS_WIDTH,
        OUTPUT_HEIGTH,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        ObjectClass::Custom
    };
    Objects.push_back(&Output);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
);

LRESULT CALLBACK canvasWndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
);

int __stdcall wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
) {
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"myVirtualSandbox Window Class";

    // A window class defines a set of behaviors that several windows 
    // might have in common. Every window must be associated with a 
    // window class. To register a window class, fill in a "WNDCLASS" 
    // structure and call "RegisterClass" function afterwards.
    WNDCLASS applicationWndClass = { };

    applicationWndClass.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    applicationWndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    applicationWndClass.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    if (!RegisterClass(&applicationWndClass))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Create the window.
    HWND hApplicationWnd = CreateWindow(
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hApplicationWnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hApplicationWnd, nShowCmd);

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
) {
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        WNDCLASS canvasWndClass = { };
        canvasWndClass.lpfnWndProc = canvasWndProc;
        canvasWndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
        canvasWndClass.lpszClassName = L"myVirtualSandbox Canvas Class";

        RegisterClass(&canvasWndClass);

        // The following loop iterates through the container of user 
        // interface objects.
        for (int i = 0; i < MyObjects.Objects.size(); ++i) {
            UiObjects::Object* pObject = MyObjects.Objects[i];

            pObject->hObjectWnd = CreateWindow(
                pObject->lpClassName, // Window class
                pObject->lpWindowName,    // Window text
                pObject->dwStyle, // Styles 
                pObject->x, // Horizontal position 
                pObject->y, // Vertical position 
                pObject->Width, // Width
                pObject->nHeigth, // Height
                hWnd, // Parent window
                pObject->hMenu, // No menu.
                hInstance,
                NULL // Pointer not needed.
            );
        }

        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    // To paint the window the "WM_PAINT" message has to be 
    // received by the window. It is sent by either the program 
    // itself or the operating system.
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // The "rcPaint" member of the "PAINTSTRCUT" structure 
        // returns a "RECT" structure that specifies the upper 
        // left and lower right corners of the rectangle in which 
        // the painting is requested.
        PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct = { };

        HDC hDeviceContext = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
        HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(66,66,66));

        // Paint application background.
        FillRect(
            hDeviceContext,
            &paintStruct.rcPaint,
            hBrush
        );

        DeleteObject(hBrush);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);

        break;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK canvasWndProc(
    HWND hCanvasWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
) {
    switch (uMsg)
    {

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        POINT point = { };

        point.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        point.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Clicked in Canvas.");

        HWND hOutputWnd = MyObjects.Output.hObjectWnd;

        // Check if hObjectWnd is a valid handle
        if (IsWindow(hOutputWnd))
        {
            SendMessage(hOutputWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)L"Test.");
        }
        else {
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("Is not..");
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hCanvasWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I did the change as recommended and tried to update the value of the structure member with `MyObjects.Objects[i].hObjectWnd = hObjectWnd` but that is not working yet. If I add a watch to the variable it says `<unable to read memory>` or similar after the assignment.

Comment: @thielo06 Then you are doing something else wrong that we cant see. Please edit your question to provide a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action.